# Android activate monitor mode

Tags: android, wifi

Does anybody knows, if it is possible to activate monitor mode without the hack of https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/?

Or does someone knows another possibility to show every active wifi client in the range of the Android device? I want to write an app, that lists all these devices. My device should not be connected to some hotspot and then port scanning. The only way I found, was the monitor mode.